# how can i call mapped uri form link?

Tags: java, grails, url-mapping

```
"/list"(
    controller:"register",
    action:"list")
```

i have written  that in urlmapping file then,in my index.gsp i have,

```
  <g:link uri="/list">Click for new registration</g:link>
```

now when i click on link it should display me only list in url but i am still getting controller name, why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

actually never saw the uri parameter in g:link.

see reference:

http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html

g:link url though needs two parameters. controller and action.

as you have a non-standard url-mapping (/controller/action) g:link is not the best solution here. 
static links though should work:

```
<a href="/yourAction">link</a>
```

Comment: The link tag should still work if the specified controller & action is right, and I think it's better to let Grails handle the link creation.

Comment: I used link with controller n action only,from action i redirected it to url which i mapped.but now this i need to do for every action of every controller writing mapping for each action..this eats my time.is there any way to do that dinamically

Comment: I mean i don want to write url mapping for each action.mapping should take controller n action name dynamically and create a map name for it. may be action name only.is there any way to do that?